# Value of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n^{(2)}x^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n^{(3)}x^n$

Tags: calculus, summation

I can find series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_nx^n = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}$$

but I can't find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n^{(2)}x^n$$   and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n^{(3)}x^n$$

$H_n^{(p)}=1+\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}+...+\frac{1}{n^p}$

Step by step solutions would be hugely appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\text{Li}_3(x)}{1-x},$$
quite obviously. If 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n x^n $$
and $A_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$, we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} A_n x^n = \frac{f(x)}{1-x}.$$